# Can't give a admin role in GitHub repository

Tags: github

So, I have a public repository where I want to invite people and give them roles with admin access. But there's no drop-down list with these options. How i can fix that? The repository is public and does not have any other settings except the default ones.

Link to this repo: https://github.com/staaankey/test

[image]

Comment: Personal repositories don't have roles, only "collaborators" with write access. You have to create an organization and transfer the repository into it; there, you have more fine-grained permission levels.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Should other collaborators be members of this organization? I just wanted to give access to at least two collaborators in to "Settings" section in the repository. With role "collaborators" they can't access there

Comment: "Collaborator" is usually the term for people with access to a personal repository, which by definition isn't in an organization (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)). For roles in organizations, see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/roles-in-an-organization).

Comment: Confusingly, repos in organizations can also have "outside collaborators"; these are users who aren't members of the organization. It's easier to make people members instead, I'd say.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you, if you want you can post this as an answer and I will accept it